# for loop out of index after running function from other view controller

Tags: swift, xcode, uiviewcontroller, segue

I have a PopupViewController that calls a function from my GameViewController which has been working perfectly until now.

```
//from my game view controller

for i in 0...6 {
            imagesAll[i].setImage(nil, for: .normal)
        }
        
        if cardIndex != 0 {
            for i in 0...cardIndex - 1 {
                imagesAll[i].setImage(cards.map({$0.image})[i], for: .normal)
            }
        }
```

I have tested this code hundreds of times and it has been fine. This is part of my reset() function of my GameViewController. In my PopupViewController, I call the function gameVC.removingCard() with parameters

```
//in my popup view controller

@IBAction func removePressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        gameVC.removingCard(indexToRemove: index!)
        
    }
```

which contains the function resetImages() with parameters

```
    func removingCard(indexToRemove: Int) {
        
        ...
        ...
        ...
        
        
        resetImages(cards: myDeck)
        ...
        ...
        ...

    }
```

and when it is called, now I get the out of index error which I haven't gotten in weeks of testing code. Is there something I'm not doing correctly when calling this code from other VC? I know this isn't much code to work with, but maybe there's something obvious I am missing.

```
{
        let parentsOne = cards.suffix(2)
        var imagesAll: [UIButton] = []
        if isPlayerOneTurn {
            imagesAll = imageArray
        } else {
            imagesAll = imageArray2
        }
        
        
        
        var cardIndex = cards.count - 2
        for i in 0...6 {          //this line: Out Of Index Error
            imagesAll[i].setImage(nil, for: .normal)
        }
        
        if cardIndex != 0 {
            for i in 0...cardIndex - 1 {
                imagesAll[i].setImage(cards.map({$0.image})[i], for: .normal)
            }
        }
        
        if gameManager.pileCards.count == 0 {
            drawingCard.setImage(nil, for: .normal)
        } else {
            drawingCard.setImage(gameManager.pileCards.last?.image, for: .normal)
        }
        
        if gameManager.secondPile.count == 0 {
            secondDraw.setImage(nil, for: .normal)
        } else {
            secondDraw.setImage(gameManager.secondPile.last?.image, for: .normal)
        }
        
        if gameManager.studentPile.count == 0 {
            studentTableCard.setImage(nil, for: .normal)
        } else {
            studentTableCard.setImage(gameManager.studentPile.last?.image, for: .normal)
        }
        
        if isPlayerOneTurn {
            onePParent1.setImage(parentsOne.map({$0.image}).first!, for: .normal)
            onePParent2.setImage(parentsOne.map({$0.image}).last!, for: .normal)
        } else {
            twoPParent1.setImage(parentsOne.map({$0.image}).first!, for: .normal)
            twoPParent2.setImage(parentsOne.map({$0.image}).last!, for: .normal)
        }
    }
```

EDIT

Im not removing an index, that function is just named to mark a certain card in an array's index position.

EDIT

So after even more exploration, I discover when the function is called from another view controller the buttons in my imagesAll array are not reached, they are declared as nil. Why are my IBOutlets declared as nil from other view controller?

Comment: you need to break the loop after removing an index

Comment: or if you are removing multiple indexes at the same time then first reverse the array of indexes which you want to remove and break the loop after last index removal

Answer (score 0):

you have to call this gameVC.removingCard(indexToRemove: index!) before dismiss your ViewController.

Comment: This is a comment not a Answer

Comment: I tried this initially, it didn't work, but I'll write the function before the dismiss anyway for now

Comment: How you get index can you share full snippet of your code?

Comment: I edited the code to include the entire function which causes the crash, the specific line is noted

Comment: As I keep trying things, I've noticed my array of buttons are nil instead of the 7 IBoutlets I've previously declared. While are my buttons nil when function called from other view controller?